# large number of Channels Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I was wondering if Kafka has any limitation or starts slowing down (due to GC or other reasons) if we have large number of channels. We have a heavy volume of data that we will be sending through Kafka (Over 2B data points). We were thinking of having about 1600 channels to start with.

Has anyone come across issues when we have such large number of channels in Kafka? Similarly, do you see issues with local DC replication with these large number of channels and lastly any foreseeable issues  if we are using MirrorMaker for cross DC replication with such large number of channels

Any pointers are highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is no hard limit on number of topics in Kafka itself. However, since Kafka stores topic info in Zookeeper (//brokers/topics/), and Zookeeper has a 1MB limitation on max node size, there can be only a finite number of topics. Also, Kafka brokers store data for different topics in /var/kafka/data/. Performance may suffer if there are too many subdirs in /var/kafka/data/.

I haven't tried thousands of topics but Kafka with a few hundred topics works ok for my purposes. The only area where I had problems was dynamic topic creation while using high level consumer. It required client re-connection to pick up the new topics on all consumer boxes. This caused time consuming consumer re-balancing (which sometimes failed, preventing reading from some topics). As a result I had to switch to simple consumer and take care about read coordination in my code.

I'd recommend to create a simple test app that generates some random data for the number of topics you expect going forward and verify that performance is acceptable.